# Video streaming getting distorted QImage

Tags: python, multithreading, opencv, pyqt, video-streaming

I am trying to make a multi camera video streaming using OpenCV and have used PyQt for GUI. The code is running fine in Full HD but the streams are getting distorted when I change the resolution of the display. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Following are the screenshots for your reference:

Screenshot in 1920*1080(Full HD)

[image]

Screenshot in 1600*900

[image]

Screenshot in 1366*768

[image]

The code is below:

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
from threading import Thread
from collections import deque
from datetime import datetime
import time
import sys
import cv2
import imutils

class CameraWidget(QtGui.QWidget):

    def __init__(self, width, height, stream_link=0, aspect_ratio=False, parent=None, deque_size=1):
        super(CameraWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        # Initialize deque used to store frames read from the stream
        self.deque = deque(maxlen=deque_size)

        self.screen_width = width
        self.screen_height = height
        self.maintain_aspect_ratio = aspect_ratio

        self.camera_stream_link = stream_link

        # Flag to check if camera is valid/working
        self.online = False
        self.capture = None
        self.video_frame = QtGui.QLabel()

        self.load_network_stream()

        # Start background frame grabbing
        self.get_frame_thread = Thread(target=self.get_frame, args=())
        self.get_frame_thread.daemon = True
        self.get_frame_thread.start()

        # Periodically set video frame to display
        self.timer = QtCore.QTimer()
        self.timer.timeout.connect(self.set_frame)
        self.timer.start(.5)

        print('Started camera: {}'.format(self.camera_stream_link))

    def load_network_stream(self):
        """Verifies stream link and open new stream if valid"""

        def load_network_stream_thread():
            if self.verify_network_stream(self.camera_stream_link):
                self.capture = cv2.VideoCapture(self.camera_stream_link)
                self.online = True
        self.load_stream_thread = Thread(target=load_network_stream_thread, args=())
        self.load_stream_thread.daemon = True
        self.load_stream_thread.start()

    def verify_network_stream(self, link):
        """Attempts to receive a frame from given link"""

        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(link)
        if not cap.isOpened():
            return False
        cap.release()
        return True

    def get_frame(self):
        """Reads frame, resizes, and converts image to pixmap"""

        while True:
            try:
                if self.capture.isOpened() and self.online:
                    # Read next frame from stream and insert into deque
                    status, frame = self.capture.read()
                    if status:
                        self.deque.append(frame)
                    else:
                        self.capture.release()
                        self.online = False
                else:
                    # Attempt to reconnect
                    print('attempting to reconnect', self.camera_stream_link)
                    self.load_network_stream()
                    self.spin(2)
                self.spin(.001)
            except AttributeError:
                pass

    def spin(self, seconds):
        """Pause for set amount of seconds, replaces time.sleep so program doesnt stall"""

        time_end = time.time() + seconds
        while time.time() < time_end:
            QtGui.QApplication.processEvents()

    def set_frame(self):
        """Sets pixmap image to video frame"""

        if not self.online:
            self.spin(1)
            return

        if self.deque and self.online:
            # Grab latest frame
            frame = self.deque[-1]

            # Keep frame aspect ratio
            if self.maintain_aspect_ratio:
                self.frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=self.screen_width)
            # Force resize
            else:
                self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))

            # Convert to pixmap and set to video frame
            self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, self.frame.shape[1], self.frame.shape[0], QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
            self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
            self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)

    def get_video_frame(self):
        return self.video_frame
```

Comment: So which method is being used for resizing the images: `imutils.resize` or `imutils.resize` ?

Comment: I didnt use PyQt before but I am familiar with Qt. In my opinion, the width and height of the frames should be same with the UI. If not you can get such kind of results.

Comment: @ZdaR cv2.resize is getting used here not the imutils.resize since the if condition is False

Comment: @YunusTemurlenk if that's the case then why is it working in Full HD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, QImage was responsible for the trouble.

```
            else:
                self.frame = cv2.resize(frame, (self.screen_width, self.screen_height))
                self.frame = cv2.cvtColor(self.frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                h, w, ch = self.frame.shape
                bytesPerLine = ch * w

            # Convert to pixmap and set to video frame

            self.img = QtGui.QImage(self.frame, w, h, bytesPerLine, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888)
            self.pix = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.img)
            self.video_frame.setPixmap(self.pix)
```